# Use custom built and placed shared libjpeg and imagemagick in xcode project

Tags: xcode, macos, imagemagick, shared-libraries, libjpeg

I'm looking to get ImageMagick and a few image libraries to work for some image downscaling in an Objective-C Mac project built via Xcode.

I have ImageMagick compiled (and libjpeg) and referenced in the project correctly. I can call on the library and return valid pointers, but because I can't get ImageMagick to see libjpeg correctly, it fails out reading a JPEG because it doesn't see the delegate where it expects.

I would like help figuring out how to configure imagemagick such that it can be told where libjpeg (and the others) will be. I do not plan on being able to use /usr/local/ directories for include & lib, but instead a directory within the project where the rest of the code sits, otherwise I would just brew or port install the libs.

Note, these are all to be shared (e.g. not static) libraries. My target SDK and platform is Mac OS X 10.9+.

Comment: Have you looked in your equivalent of `imagemagick/6.8.8-9/etc/ImageMagick-6/delegates.xml`

Comment: I looked a little, but I found the format to be confusing, could you explain in more detail in a response,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out part of the issue was that I didn't do `make clean` between `configure` changes. However, I still had to add in the `lib` & `include` paths for each of my image libraries, in this case to the `CPPFLAGS` and `LFLAGS`. Now it works great, and I didn't have to touch the delegates XML file.